# Getting error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'entryID'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

usp_auditRejectRequest:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a01].[usp_auditRejectRequest]
(@accountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , @GroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [a01].[tbl_enrollmentAudits]
        (entryID,entryDate, requestID, accountID, groupID, accepted, reason)
    VALUES( NULL,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), NULL, @accountID, @GroupID, 0, NULL);
END
GO
```

usp_auditAcceptRequest:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a01].[usp_auditAcceptRequest]
(@accountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , @GroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [a01].[tbl_enrollmentAudits]
        ( entryID,entryDate, requestID, accountID, groupID, accepted, reason)
    VALUES( NULL,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), NULL, @accountID, @GroupID, 1, NULL);
END
GO
```

usp_addRequest:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a01].[usp_addRequest]
(@AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @GroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF ([a01].[udf_isUserActive](@AccountID) = 0)
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE [a01].[usp_auditRejectRequest]
            @AccountID, @GroupID

        RETURN;
    END;

    IF ([a01].[udf_isUserBlockedFromGroup](@GroupID)=0)
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE [a01].[usp_auditRejectRequest]
             @AccountID, @GroupID

        RETURN;
    END;
END;
GO
```

Output: Add an inactive user:

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @GroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;


    (SELECT @AccountID = accountID 
    FROM [a01].[tbl_userAccounts] WHERE accountUsername='adrianab');

    (SELECT @GroupID = groupID FROM [a01].[tbl_groups] WHERE groupName LIKE '%Foo%');

    EXECUTE [a01].[usp_addRequest] @AccountID, @GroupID;
END;
GO
```

I cannot declare any more UNIQUE IDENTIFIEd,accountId and groupID are the only ones i can use as instructed by our lecturer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Procedure or function !!! has too many arguments specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292705/procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified)

Comment: when i used 2 parameters, another error msg shows up that "a null value cannot be inserted into entryID". AS entryID is a PK I suppose! error msg:"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'entryID', table tbl_enrollmentAudits'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Comment: Don't change the question to a new question when the original question is answered.  The posted accepted answer is to the first question so this will makes no sense unless someone goes through the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    EXECUTE [a01].[usp_auditRejectRequest]
>          NULL,NULL,NULL,@AccountID,@GroupID,0,'User not active'
> ```

You are calling the `usp_auditRejectRequest` procedure with 7 parameters when it only defines 2 parameters.  Either add more parameters to your procedure (which you say you can't do), or just call it with 2 and move the "reason" value to the sproc:

```
    EXECUTE [a01].[usp_auditRejectRequest]
         @AccountID,@GroupID
```

Comment: when i used 2 parameters, another error msg shows up that "a null value cannot be inserted into entryID". AS entryID is a PK I suppose! error msg:"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'entryID', table tbl_enrollmentAudits'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: Does `entryID` get set automatically?  Then don't have in on your field list.    If it does not, then set it to a valid, non-null value.

Comment: entryID is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, what do you mean by "Valid"?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - does it get set to a value automatically when a new record is inserted?  If not, just use `newid()` to generate a new non-null value.

Comment: OK it worked after setting entryID to NEWID(), thank you