# Procedure has too many arguments specified. it inserts the first row and gives that error on the second row

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert all `DataGridView` rows into a database.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            sqlcon.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SaveWorkerSchedulePerDay", sqlcon);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            for (int i = 0; i < eachDayScheduleDG.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@worker_id", eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeEnter", Convert.ToDateTime(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeExit", Convert.ToDateTime(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costPerDay", getCostDays(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), i));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error: "+ ex);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Procedure has too many arguments specified.

I know that it's inserting the first row without any errors.

Comment: well the database is saying that you passed t many arguments to a stored procedure. / function. Since we dont get to see any of the source code we cant really say

Comment: please post the code for stored procedure too.

Comment: No need for the code of the proc. You aren't clearing the parameters collection of the SqlCommand between executions of your loop. See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272734/93922

Comment: Learn about databinding and you wont have to loop thru DGV rows at all!  One line of code adds, updates and deletes as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the two lines that create the command and move them inside the for loop. That way you aren't trying to keep adding more parameters for each row all into the same command.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are adding more and more parameters to your command at each iteration of the for-loop.

Instead, reuse the parameters like this:

```
// First, create the parameters without values.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@worker_id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeEnter", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeExit", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@costPerDay", SqlDbType.Decimal);

for (int i = 0; i < eachDayScheduleDG.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Assign the values to the existing parameters.
    cmd.Parameters["@day"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    cmd.Parameters["@worker_id"].Value = eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters["@timeEnter"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    cmd.Parameters["@timeExit"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    cmd.Parameters["@costPerDay"].Value = getCostDays(eachDayScheduleDG.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), i);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Make sure to use the correct `SqlDbType` constants.